# How to access a C: drive of one PC from another, that is on a different network?

Tags: windows-7, networking, hard-drive, router

I'm trying to connect to another computers c: Drive that is on a different network.

To be clear: 2 computers connected to two different routers and those routers are connected to each other with serial ports. so the two computers are on two different networks.

Network of PC 1:
200.10.10.0 255.255.255.0

Network of the routers:
200.10.12.0 255.255.255.0

Network of PC 2
200.10.11.0 255.255.255.0

As i said does anyone know how to access the c: drive of one computer from the other.if you have any questions you could ask just ask thanks.

Thanks,
 Malak

Comment: The 2 routers are connected via their "serial ports"?! Are you sure? What router model and how do they communicate?

Comment: yes they are connected via serial ports, and their model is Cisco 2501.

Comment: Ah! I wasn't thinking far enough back into history!

Comment: Can you not reconfigure them into a single network or do you really need the 3 networks? Are the routers configured to correctly route all the ports required for Windows networking?

Comment: i need the three networks, but i used the network connection settings in windows to make the two computers see each other.(by that i mean in the connections it shows the connections that the two are working on). I had to maek a vpn server on one, and then connect to it with the other computer. I can't figure out how to do file sharing between the two pcs.

Comment: Also these are like 1990s routers XD

Comment: So you need to update your question with details about how you configured the VPN, what type of VPN is it, etc.

Comment: ok, you see i turned one computer into a vpn server by going this link http://www.howtogeek.com/135996/how-to-create-a-vpn-server-on-your-windows-computer-without-installing-any-software

Comment: Also i made a connection with the other PC so it can connect to  the server(which is PC 1). In the network and sharing center i see two networks. One i think is the vpn, and the other is the connection to the router. What i cant get is how to open file sharing between the two PCs. Do i set up a network sharing thing, in that network? because that network has the two pcs in it.

Comment: to be clear in the network and sharing center i see network 1, which is the computer and the router. Also i see network 2 which i think is the vpn. im not sure how to test it if the two pcs connected via this network. But i think its correct. thanks for the help